# check if validation fails (with custom mesages)

Tags: laravel

When using the validation like below with custom messages how is possible to check if the validation fails?

```
$rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email'
];

$customMessages = [
    'email.required' => 'The email is required.',
    'email.email' => 'Please insert a valid email.'
];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

Like below, without custom messages is possible to use `$validator->fails()` but in the above case how to verify if the validation fails?

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    //...
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: if you wan to use `$validator->fails()` then use `Validator::make` with custom message. pass your custom message as third param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$this->validate` it validate your request against your validation rules and if failed then it redirect to previous page with validation message. If you want to use `$validator->fails()` then use `Validator::make` with custom message. Like this

```
$rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email'
];

$customMessages = [
    'email.required' => 'The email is required.',
    'email.email' => 'Please insert a valid email.'
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $customMessages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
   //...
}
```

Check validator make method https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.html#method_make

Answer (score 0):

much simpler solution is to use custom handler in app\Exceptions\Handler.php:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (ValidationException $e, $request) {
        //list of specific failed tests
        $e->validator->failed();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'custom message','meow'=>'meow',$e->status);
    });
}
```

this way you keep old behavior AND can still change messages sent back to the user/frontend